# Ruby BigDecimal - bug?

Tags: ruby

Something strange is going on with BigDecimal when you take the sqrt of a small number but specify a very high level of precision...

When I say strange, I mean the sqrt of 36 is 5.

Can anyone explain whats going on here or is this a bug...

```
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'bigdecimal/util'

@d = BigDecimal.new(36)
puts @d.sqrt(250).to_i

$ ruby1.9 test.rb 
5

$ ruby1.9 -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin10]

$ uname -a
Darwin jack.bidcactus.local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011;
```

Comment: Hint: compiler bugs are exceedingly rare.  When you see hoof prints, you should probably suspect horses not zebras.  In this case, "horses" means "You don't understand what you're doing" and "zebras" means "You discovered something that the millions of other users and developers of Ruby have somehow overlooked".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns a float. This is why you see the "strange" behavior.   This is not therefore a bug. [API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Math.html#method-c-sqrt)

code:

```
           static VALUE
math_sqrt(VALUE obj, VALUE x)
{
    double d0, d;

    Need_Float(x);
    d0 = RFLOAT_VALUE(x);
    /* check for domain error */
    if (d0 < 0.0) domain_error("sqrt");
    if (d0 == 0.0) return DBL2NUM(0.0);
    d = sqrt(d0);
    return DBL2NUM(d);
}
```

Comment: Since I'm using the BigDecimal class, I expected it to return the value as a BigDecimal rather than a float..  The point of BigDecimal is to provide more precision than a float otherwise would.  Thanks.

Comment: This code is for the `Math.sqrt` method. He is calling `BigDecimal#sqrt`, which returns a BigDecimal instance, as expected. The problem is that `to_i` is truncating all nines of `5.99999999...`. Try `.to_f` or `round` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Square root of 36 is 6. When Ruby evaluates it with this precision, it gets 5.9999... As you calls `to_i`, you rounds down the value, getting 5 instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `to_i`, you are removing all of the decimal precision created by the square rooting. When you call `to_i`, the almost infinite trail of `9`s after the `5` (seen my removing `to_i`). If you want to do that, you might want to call `round` before calling `to_i`.

Comment: Replacing to_i with round actually generates the same behevior.. I thought it would be returning a BigDecimal still rather than a float as pointed out above..